# Creating a Junit that will fail if user inputs a blank search for a RandomAccess file

Tags: java, junit

I'm trying to make a JUnit test for a RandomAccess file (rStream) that will fail if the user inserts a blank input when searching for the file. I'm having difficulty however and would like some help.

```
@Test
public void testOpenDB() 
{
  mainApp tester = new mainApp();

  assertNotNull("error", tester.openDB(rStream));
}
```

Comment: take a look at this tutorial http://www.vogella.com/articles/JUnit/article.html

Comment: just out of curiousity: Isn't blank input by user something your program should take care of? I think your should rather test whether your program handles this gracefully

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're trying to test a Swing UI here.  Is that what your `mainApp` is?

I'd expect your app to throw some kind of exception if its contract isn't fulfilled.  If that's true, they you simply need to add an `@expected` annotation to the test method and say which exception class will be thrown.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, but it still seems to cause a crash when run.


 @Test (expected = FileNotFoundException.class)
 public void testOpenDB() throws FileNotFoundException
 {
  mainApp tester = new mainApp();
  
  
  tester.openDB();
 }
Here is my method in the mainApp for reference.
 public void openDB() {
  kb.nextLine();
  System.out.println("Name of your Database?\n");
  this.rStream = new RandomAccess(kb.nextLine(), "r", true);
 }

Comment: If the code you're testing doesn't throw an exception, then it won't be caught.  And "crash" had better mean "unexpected behavior, but the test runs successfully."  I see how test for a an empty database name.  Why don't you check for it and throw an IllegalArgumentException if that's your contract?